# How to bind a variable in to url parameter using href Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, href

I am not able to bind variable in to a url as a parameter using href in angular

https://example.com/a.action?type='+{{b}}">

when ever I put the variable under interpolation or bind [href] it is not clickable and also not working

Answer (score 3):

For your view:

```
<a [routerLink]="['../user' + user.id]">{{user.name}}</a>
```

or with params

```
<a [routerLink]="['/profile/3']" [queryParams]="{position:'boss', 'salary': 'expensive' }">
```

Controller URL manipulation

```
this.router.navigate(['profile/3'], { queryParams: { position: pos, 'salary': 'expensive' } }); // add .then(() => {}) for promise
```

To get the route info: `private route: ActivatedRoute`

To update the route: `private router: Router`